# Containerized spring app not seeing local files?

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I have a spring boot application and a postgresql database. I run both of them in containers with `docker-compose`. The thing is, normal calls, for ex. `localhost:8080/api/users` return normal values and act as normal.

However, when I try to access `localhost:8080/api/images/x.png` it is supposed to return an image, but I get this instead:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File '/tmp/tomcat-docbase.9528987821055837875.8080/images/Mercedes-Benz-190E-Sedan-2.0 Petrol-1989-Engine.png' does not exist
```

This was the initial Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

I changed it to this:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
ADD . ./src/main/webapp/images/
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Now when I try to access the image I get this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File '/src/main/webapp/images/Mercodes-Benz-190E-Sedan-2.0 Petrol-1989-Engine.png' does not exist
```

When the application is launched locally from the IDE the calls work perfectly fine, maybe my setup of Dockerfile is just wrong? I'm still very new to docker, any tips are appreciated.

EDIT: The image files are located in src/main/webapp/images/{files}

Comment: There is no `src/main/webapp` as that is the root of your application. You cannot access a resource as a `java.util.File` when it is packaged in a jar/war you can only load that as an inputstream. So fix your controller/handler that should return this.

Comment: Or you can just add a volume to your container..

Comment: @k-wasilewski how would I do that here

Comment: use a --volume tag or just create a docker-compose.yml