# Use InputStream instead of FileUtils?

Tags: java

I need to convert my controller to return the type of Input Stream, as this is one of the solutions to fix my problem with Docker.

My current controller:

```
@GetMapping("/api/images/{filename}")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(@PathVariable("filename") String filename) {
    String FILE_PATH_ROOT = context.getRealPath("/images/");
    byte[] image = new byte[0];
    try {
        image = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(FILE_PATH_ROOT + filename));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG).body(image);
}
```

Any idea how do I rewrite this as an InputStream type method? The goal is to return an image itself using a given name.

For context this is my previous post that spawned this current question - [Containerized spring app not seeing local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67111769/containerized-spring-app-not-seeing-local-files)

Comment: Do you want to return `InputStream` or `ResponseEntity<InputStream>`?

Comment: I suppose just 'InputStream' ? Would have to fool around with both to see which one works

Comment: I suppose you might want to remove everything from the question mark to the end of the URL in the last paragraph, as it should probably link to the question, not to a comment below it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the manual approach:

```java
File file=new File(FILE_PATH_ROOT + filename));
byte[] image=new byte[(int)file.length()];
try(BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream (new FileInputStream(file)){
    bis.read(image);
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This can be simplified using `Files.readAllBytes`:

```java
File file=new File(FILE_PATH_ROOT + filename));
byte[] image=Files.readAllBytes(Path.of(FILE_PATH_ROOT + filename));
```

Or just change the method to return a `RequestBody<InputStream>`:

```java
@GetMapping("/api/images/{filename}")
public ResponseEntity<InputStream> getImage(@PathVariable("filename") String filename) {
    String FILE_PATH_ROOT = context.getRealPath("/images/");
    try{
        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG).body(new BufferedInputStream (new FileInputStream (new File(FILE_PATH_ROOT + filename))));
    }catch(IOException e){
        return ResponseEntity.notFound();
    }
}
```