# Add local images to docker volume

Tags: docker

How do I add images to a volume in docker? And then add that volume to a container I presume? My original problem is here - [Containerized spring app not seeing local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67111769/containerized-spring-app-not-seeing-local-files) What I need to figure out is how to add my image files to a volume so then I could access them.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

The app is a spring boot api, images are located in src/main/webapp/images/

Comment: Where does the volume come in?  Your other question hints at static assets for a Web application; are you trying to `COPY *.png` into the Docker image, or copy seed data from the Docker image into a data volume, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to copy png files into my docker image.

Comment: How does the application access them?  What `COPY` line do you have already?  What error do you get?

Comment: My dockerfile currently looks the same as in the question. The error I get when I try to access the image - `java.io.FileNotFoundException: File '/tmp/tomcat-docbase.9528987821055837875.8080/images/Mercedes-Benz-190E-Sedan-2.0 Petrol-1989-Engine.png' does not exist`